# QGIS Plugin 'make' error on Windows

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, compile, mingw

Creating QGIS plugin via PluginBuilder and compiling resources via simple 'make' works straightforward under Linux (SuSe 13.2).
Under Windows 'make' (3.81) produces an error:

```
C:\Users\Jochen\.qgis2\python\plugins\ALBa>make
pyrcc4 -o resources.py  resources.qrc
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, pyrcc4 -o resources.py resources.qrc, ...) failed.
make (e=2): Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.
make: *** [resources.py] Fehler 2
```

[The system can not find the file specified]

What is my problem (besides using Win...) ?

Comment: looks like the system can't find a file - resources.py? or may be one of it's requirements

Comment: But wich file is missing? resources.py does not exist directly after creating the plugin with plugin builder. It is created by 'make'. So how can I find out about what is missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved this. Using MINGW32 on Windows does the trick (not cmd).

In detail, this ...

[image]

... opens the shell that looks like this:

[image]

Further reading about MinGW (Minimalist GNU for Windows): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW

Comment: +1 same problem, same solution. Because I never heard from mingw32, have to read about it, now I learned to use the MSYS-Shell

Comment: that's so great about SE, one never stops learning :-)